# Wann darf man Markennamen bevorzugen?

Tags: brand-name, colloquial

Es gibt einige Beispiele für Markennamen, die inzwischen in den deutschen Sprachgebrauch so sehr integriert wurden, dass man bereits folgende Konversationen beobachten kann:

> "Kannst Du mir ein Papiertaschentuch geben?" - "Ach so, ein *Tempo*. Bitte schön!"
>
> "In welcher Schublade ist noch einmal der *Tesa*?"

Wann sollte man eher die gebräuchlichen Markennamen verwenden, und wann greift man besser auf die ursprünglichen Bezeichnungen zurück?

Comment: Hm, das muss ich *googeln*. ;-)

Comment: Hab mir mal die Freiheit genommen Deinen Beispielsatz zu korrigieren. :)

Comment: @Takkat: Gegenfrage: Wie bestimmt man das Geschlecht? Bei uns sagt man nämlich *das Tesa(film)* ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ich habe 5 min. darüber nachgedacht - ist eigentlich eine weitere gute Frage. Habe mich für Film *m* entschieden, Band *n* geht warscheinlich auch.

Comment: Der Tesa(film), das Tesa(band), die Tesa(rolle).  Ich würde "das" nehmen, und ich find "der" irgendwie... falsch.  ;-P

Comment: @OregonGhost bei uns auch.

Comment: Diese Dinge sind regional sehr unterschiedlich. Ich würde da nicht Worte wie "Fön" und "Walkman" mit anderen in einen Topf werfen. (Klar ist Nutella gebräuchlich, aber wenn ich nach Nutella frage, will ich keine Nuss-Nougat-Creme vom Diskonter.) Und jetzt geh ich mir ein Tixo kaufen und bestelle dann im Gasthaus ein Obi.

Comment: @Phira Bei mir im Elternhaus gab es immer 'Nutella' vom Aldi. 'Nutella' ist für mich ein Gattungsbegriff. Und dann gibt es noch die 'echte Nutella'.

Comment: "Nur wo Nutella drauf steht ..."

Comment: @Phira:   Und dann gibt es noch die echte Nutella von Aldi. - Die fand ich immer am besten.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Um die Frage beantworten zu können, müsste man definieren, was mit "bevorzugen dürfen" genau gemeint ist.

Ich denke, in der gesprochenen Sprache ist es kein Problem - unter der Voraussetzung, dass du regionale Unterschiede berücksichtigst. In vielen Fällen klingt es sogar natürlicher, einen generalisierten Markennamen wie *Tempo* oder *Fön* zu verwenden. Und: Wer sagt schon *Nuss-Nougat-Creme* statt *Nutella*?

In offiziellen Dokumenten hingegen würde ich abwägen, ob die Verwendung zu Missverständnissen führen könnte und vielleicht immer einen allgemeinen Produktnamen verwenden. Es könnte auch sein, dass ein Unternehmen nicht möchte, dass ein Markennamen generalisiert wird, weil es wirtschaftliche Nachteile mit sich bringen könnte, wenn ein von ihm Produktname durch die allgemeine Verwendung zu einem Gattungsnamen wird.

Interessant ist in diesem Zusammenhang auch, dass sich auch Verben aus Markennamen entwickeln können. Beispiele: googeln, flexen ([Winkelschleifer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winkelschleifer)) und [föhnen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/foehnen).

Hier ist übrigens eine Liste, die ich [hier](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/markennamen) gefunden und etwas angepasst habe:

```
Markenname      Inhaber                   Generische Bezeichnung
--------------- ------------------------- -----------------------------
Aspirin         Bayer                     ASS (Acetylsalicylsäure)
Bobby-Car       BIG Spielwarenfabrik      Rutschauto
Caro-Kaffee     Nestlé                    Getreide(ersatz)kaffee
Carrera-Bahn    Stadlbauer                (spurgebundene) Autorennbahn
Fön             AEG Hausgeräte            Haartrockner
Glitzi          Vileda                    (Scheuer)Schwamm
Inbus-Schlüssel Bauer & Schaurte Karcher  Innensechskantschraubendreher
Jeep            Fiat Chrysler             Geländewagen
Kaba            Kraft Foods               Kakaopulver
Kornspitz       Backaldrin                
Matchbox-Auto   Mattel                    Spielzeug-(Modell-)Auto
Maxi-Cosi       Dorel                     Babyschale
Moc             Dalli Werke               Scheuermilch
Nutella         Ferrero                   Nuss-Nougat-Creme
Nylon           DuPont                    Polyamid
Pampers         Procter & Gamble          Windeln
Philadelphia    Kraft Foods               Doppelrahmfrischkäse
UHU             UHU                       Alleskleber
Q-Tip           Elida Fabergé             Wattestäbchen
Rollerblades    Rollerblade               Inline-Skates
Selters         Radeberger Gruppe         Mineralwasser
Tempos          SCA Hygiene Products      Papiertaschentücher
Tesa            Tesa (Beiersdorf-Tochter) Klebefilm
Tupper-Dose     Tupperware                Plastikbehälter
Walkman         Sony                      (tragbarer) Kassettenrekorder
Whirlpool       Whirlpool                 Sprudelbad
Zewa            SCA Hygiene Products      Küchenrolle
```

Comment: Einige, wie Fön, Flex oder Selters sind wirklich sehr gebräuchlich. Bis eben wußte ich nicht einmal, daß Fön ein Markenname ist.

Comment: +1; Eine hübsche Liste; Von den genannten ist mir persönlich etwas weniger als die Hälfte wirklich als Synonym für die jeweiligen Dinge gebräuchlich (Aspirin, Bobby-Car, Fön, Nutella, Selter(s), Tempo, Tesa, Tupperdose, Walkman, Whirlpool). Philadelphia ist in meinen Augen übrigens eher synonym für *Doppelrahmfrischkäse*, nicht für Frischkäse allgemein, wenn schon.

Comment: @OregonGhost bzgl. "Philadelphia": ja, stimmt. Ich glaube, es gibt hier einige Begriffe, die subjektiv unterschiedlich empfunden werden. Hängt meiner Meinung nach davon ab, wie alt man ist und aus welcher Gegend man stammt. Für mich (41) war *Uhu* früher wirklich *das* Wort für Kleber, *Tesa* hingegen verwende ich bis heute nicht für Klebestreifen (regional bedingt).

Comment: Was für eine unglaublich schöne Liste! Fehlt nur noch das Geschlecht ;)

Comment: @splattne: Uhu kenne ich zwar aus der Kindheit (und tatsächlich findet sich bei mir und anderen Leuten meist Uhu), aber irgendwie habe ich es nie synonym benutzt. Tesa (oder eher Tesafilm) hingegen schon immer, obwohl ich eigentlich häufig eine andere Marke verwende ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Wäre hilfreich zum Lernen der Wörter, ja. Nur ist das halt nicht immer eindeutig :X

Comment: @Takkat und @OregonGhost "das Rollerblade" (j/k); Scherz beiseite: Die meisten Begriffe könnte man schon eindeutig einem Geschlecht zuordnen.

Comment: Bei uns sagt man zu Nuß-Nougat-Creme auch Schokoschmiere

Comment: Glitzi und Moc sind mir nicht geläufig.

Comment: In offiziellen Dokumenten?  Was genau ist das?  Weil... generell: Finger weg.  Markennamen heissen so weil sie (üblicherweise) geschützte Namen einer Marke sind.  Und "es könnte sein" ist falsch, "es ist" ist richtig: generalisiert heisst am Ende "Markenschutz verlieren".  Der Inhaber einer Marke *muss* diese verteidigen, sonst isse weg.  Deswegen: wer nicht abgemahnt oder am Ende verklagt werden will, lässt in "öffentlichen" Dokumenten Markennamen weg (es sei denn, es ginge wirklich um genau dieses Produkt, und die Marke wird entsprechend gekennzeichnet... aber selbst dann... und hier ist ech

Comment: @jae Ja, so ungefähr meinte ich das. Wenn ich z.B. einen Artikel für eine Zeitschrift verfasse und darin etwas über ein Papiertaschentuch schreibe, würde ich nicht "Tempo" verwenden. Hingegen würde ich in einem Roman z.B. in einer direkten Rede nicht davor zurückschrecken, um einen Dialog authentisch zu halten. (Neurotikern empfehle ich, sich im Buch - außerhalb des Haupttextes - rechtlich abzusichern).

Comment: +1 für "Innensechskantschraubendreher" und "flexen", weil das einfach herrliche Begriffe sind. Und dafür, dass ich bis heute ebenfalls nicht wusste, dass "Fön" ein Markenname ist! :) Einige davon kenne ich aber nicht, z.B. Moc und Maxi-Cosi. Und Aspirin finde ich etwas verwirrend... ich kenn nur Aspirin-Schachteln auf denen Aspirin draufsteht. Was nennt man noch so?

Comment: Die Mutter aller Markennamenbegriffe fehlt - Maggi.

Comment: Einem Unternehmen kann nichts besseres passieren, als daß ihr Produktname zum Synonym bzw. zur Gattungsbezeichnung wird. Du wirst keines finden, das sich dagegen wehrt.

Comment: Was ist denn `Wer sagt schon Nuß-Nougat-Creme statt Nutella?` für ein Argument, zumal ja möglicherweise Nutella zu einem Brotaufstrich gesagt wird, der gar keine Nutella ist.

Comment: @Ingo: Die Mutter aller Markennamen ist aber Coke, auch wenn es von der Farbe ähnlich ist.

Comment: Sehr schöne Liste. Ist bei uns nicht alles gebräuchlich, vieles davon schon. Mir fehlen noch "Fanta" (Orangenlimonade) und "Sprite" (Zitronenlimonade) in der Liste.

Comment: Statt Fön schreibe ich immer Föhn; und meinte damit trotzdem den Haarttrockner, der nach dem Fallwind beannt ist…

Comment: Noch eine Ergänzung: [Thermit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermit)

Comment: Vorsicht, Inbus steht für sich genommen erstmal nur für Innensechskant, der Inbus-Schlüssel ist also ein Innensechskantschlüssel (das L-förmige Ding mit sechseckigem Profil), ein Inbus-Schraubendreher ist ein Innensechskantschraubendreher (Schraubendreher mit vorne sechseckigem Profil).

Comment: @Raketenolli Genau. Ein **IN**nensechskant(schlüssel) der Firma **B**auer **u**nd **S**chaurte. Ein Akronym. Wie auch immer, ich vermisse Lenor. Und Pril! Es gibt ja sogar Prilwasser (Wasser mit einem Schuss Geschirrreiniger.)

Comment: Das österreichische Equivalent für den Caro-Kaffee wäre Linde-Kaffee (http://www.lindefiguren.at/geschichtliches/)

Comment: Sehr interessante Liste - mir war beispielsweise bis gerade eben nicht klar, dass *Whirlpool* ein Markenname ist und *Sprudelbad* hätte ich ehrlich gesagt nicht verstanden (vielleicht ein Bad, in das Mineralwasser eingefüllt wurde?). Ich gin bislang davon aus, dass das eines der Produkte ist, für die einfach kein deutscher Ausdruck existiert.

Comment: es heißt *föhnen* und nur föhnen ist richtig http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/foehnen

Comment: Mir fehlen in der Liste noch die Weck-Gläser :)

Answer (score 11):

Man *sollte* eigentlich nie Markennamen bevorzugen. Einige Marken sind halt nur eben in den täglichen Sprachgebrauch eingeflossen, was aber noch lange nicht bedeutet, daß sie die ursprünglichen Worte ersetzt haben.

Auch wenn jeder um dich herum von *Tempos* spricht, steht es dir trotzdem frei sie *Papiertaschentücher* zu nennen. Die offizielle Regel, wenn es denn eine gäbe, würde dir bestimmt sogar Recht geben. Es ist letztendlich Geschmacksache.

Comment: Also ich sag lieber Fön™ (Markenname von AEG) anstatt Haartrockner... :)

Comment: @FUZxxl: wobei Fö(h)n als warmer Fallwind ja recht treffend ist

Comment: Es gibt allerdings bestimmte Wörter, die ich wirklich bevorzugt verwenden würde, z.B. *Whirlpool* anstelle von *Sprudelbad*.

Answer (score 6):

> Wann greift man besser auf die ursprünglichen Bezeichnungen zurück?

Wenn Du ein Händler/Wirtschaftstreibender bist, und nicht die Marke, sondern ein Konkurrenzprodukt anbietest. Wer auf der Frühstückskarte 'Nutella' anpreist, der muss auch Nutella verkaufen, wer Tesafilm bei Ebay einstellt, der sollte auch Tesafilm haben.

Immer, wenn es um Haftungsfragen geht, und wenn Präzision essentiell wichtig ist. Wenn man als Gesundheitsminister vor dem Verzehr von Philadelphia warnt, obwohl man allgemein Frischkäse meint, oder wenn man vor Frischkäse warnt, obwohl nur Philadelphiaprodukte betroffen sind.

Answer (score 1):

Es wundert mich, dass in einem Forum, das die deutsche Sprache zum Thema hat, noch niemand auf eine offensichtliche linguistische Einschränkung hingewiesen hat: Viele der Markennamen sind nur regional gebräuchlich.

So sind etwa die Bezeichnungen *Selters, Tempo* oder *Tesa* nur in Deutschland üblich. Wer sie in der Schweiz verwendet, riskiert, nicht verstanden zu werden. Umgekehrt versteht einen womöglich in Deutschland niemand, wenn man von *Henniez, Sagex* oder *Bostitch* spricht.

Answer (score 0):

In Deutschland werden professionellen Bohrhämmer als **Hilti** bezeichnet.

Alles andere bezeichnet **semiprofessionelles Spielzeug** aus dem Baumarkt.

Ich habe keine Ahnung ob es in dieser Kategorie ernsthafte Konkurrenzprodukte gibt.

Übrigens es heißt **die Hilti**.

Comment: Ich kenne mich nicht aus, habe mir aber sagen lassen, dass DUSS Bohrhämmer auch ganz gut sein sollen. ;)

Comment: @feeela Makita ist Spitze als Presslufthammer (hab selbst schon damit gearbeitet). Hilti sind anerkanntermaßen der Maßstab bei Bohrhämmern, gibt aber auch viele Handwerker, die mit Bosch arbeiten. Auf der Baustelle lässt niemand seine Hilti aus den Augen, die Bosch dagegen kann man schon mal unbeaufsichtigt lassen :)

Comment: Diese Antwort grenzt ja schon sehr stark an Produktwerbung …