# Was ist der richtige Name für „Ohropax“?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, terminology

Es fällt mir manchmal schwer, mit Wörtern wie [Ohropax](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ohropax) umzugehen. Bei denen muss man im Wörterbuch nachschlagen, um das sich nicht auf die Marke beziehende Wort zu finden. In diesem Fall *Gehörschutzstöpsel*.

- Die Frage ist ob es sich lohnt, den quasi richtigen Begriff zu nutzen. Würde *Gehörschutzstöpsel/Ohrenstöpsel* komisch klingen?
- Wie heißt das linguistische Phänomen, in dem man den Namen eines Objektes durch den einer Marke ersetzt? (Wie im Beispiel oben oder wie *Tempo* anstelle *Taschentuchs*)

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/503/wann-darf-man-markennamen-bevorzugen

Comment: "Gehörschutzstöpsel" ist schon ziemlich lang und formal. Wie wäre es einfach mit "Ohrenstöpsel"?

Comment: @elena: Das ist auch so ziemlich, wie Ohropax ihr eigenes Produkt beschreibt: »Ohrstöpsel aus Schaumstoff gegen Lärm.«

Comment: This would be a generic(ised) trademark. It's a specialised kind of metonymy.

Comment: Ich kenne übrigens ausschließlich den Begriff Ohropax und würde bei Ohrstöpsel spontan an Kopfhörer denken (wobei mich eine Google-Suche gerade eines Besseren belehrte). Just my two cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Umgangssprachlich ware hier Ohropax sicher der üblichere Begriff, aber der „richtige“ Begriff ist sicher nicht falsch. Insbesondere wenn du auf (Schleich-)Werbung verzichten möchtest, ist bei einigen dieser Begriffe die Variante ohne Markenname zu bevorzugen.

Ich kenne das als „der Markenname ist zum Gattungsbegriff geworden“. Ob das auch eine kürzere Bezeichnung hat, weiß ich nicht. Eine der Eigenheiten dieser Umdeutung der Marke ist, dass die Leute oft nicht mehr wissen, dass dies ursprünglich ein Markenname war.

Comment: Das gibt es beispielsweise auch im Englischen häufig: Hoover, foley artist, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Ich verwende eigentlich ausschließlich »Ohrstöpsel« und höre selten mal jemanden »Ohropax« sagen.

#### Wie man solche Begriffe nennt

Im Wikipedia-Artikel »[Gattungsname](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattungsname#Markenname)« werden die Bezeichnungen

- **generalisierter Markenname** und
- **generischer Markenname**

verwendet.

Laut der sprachwissenschaftlichen Disziplin [Deonomastik](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deonomastik) wären es wohl **Deonyme**:

> […] diejenigen Anteile eines Wortschatzes, die durch Ableitung von Eigennamen (nomina propria) entstanden sind.

Genannte [Beispiele](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deonomastik#Beispiele_f.C3.BCr_Deonyme) für Firmen-/Markennamen: *Tempo*, *Tesa*, *Uhu*, *googeln*.

Mit eher wirtschaftlichem Fokus vielleicht auch **Begriffsmonopol**.

Comment: Zu den genannten Beispielen ist zu sagen, dass *Tempo* und *Tesa* in Österreich nicht als Gattungsname verwendet werden. Zu einem Papiertaschentuch nennt man in Österreich *Papiertaschentuch*, und die meistverkaufte Marke heißt *Feh*. Zu einem Klebeband sagt man *Tixo*. Lange Zeit gab es kaum eine andere Marke im Handel. Seit 1985 gibt es den ursprünglichen Tixo-Hersteller (Fa. Kores mit Sitz in Wien) nicht mehr, die Marke *Tixo* wurde von Beiersdorf gekauft, das ist dieselbe Firma, der auch Tesa gehört. Heute sind Tesa und Tixo dasselbe Produkt in zwei verschiedenen Verpackungen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, natürlich gab es ebensolche Unterschiede auch zwischen der Bundesrepublik Deutschland und der Deutschen Demokratischen Republik, und viele werden sich erhalten haben.

Answer (score 5):

*Ohrstöpsel* klingt in meinem Sprachraum (Berlin) völlig normal, da würde man eher auffallen, wenn das Wort *Ohropax* benutzt.

(Zur zweiten Frage kann ich nichts beitragen, das über [PMFs Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10464/5437) hinausginge.)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.vbg.de/apl/zh/z705/3.htm

3.1.3.2 Gehörschutzstöpsel

Alle Gehörschützer, die im Gehörgang oder in der Ohrmulde getragen werden, sind Gehörschutzstöpsel. Es sind folgende Arten zu unterscheiden...